# Help in Basics for Capacitance

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

How does [capacitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor) store a charge? I'm a little bit confused, as I know that a capacitor stores charge but how does it do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that is required to "store" a charge is "not make it run away". As you know a positive charge is attracted by a negative one and vice versa - so in a capacitor you bring positive and negative charge "close without touching". They are attracted to each other but can't reach - the insulator is in the way.

Compare this to the situation of two lovers in adjacent prison cells - they can see but they can't touch. They want to be near each other so they sit against the dividing wall. You could open their cell doors but they don't want to move away from the other for even a second. Tragic.

[image]

photo credit:  https://passthepopcornreviews.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/bright-star1.jpg

This is the same picture but with charges:

[image]

Source: http://www.rpi.edu/dept/phys/ScIT/InformationStorage/efields/images/caplines.gif

Comment: Very nicely explained Mr. Floris. Thanks a lot! :)